# Динамическое создание градиента вдоль пути SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Я динамически создаю  путь, используя  `SVG`. Далее я хочу добавить градиент к своему пути, но я застрял.

Как я пытался сделать, показано на изображении 2. Мой градиент идет вдоль пути, но мне нужно, чтобы градиент имел вид, как на изображении 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение 2

Мои определения `gradient` и `stroke` следующие:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
        <linearGradient id = "grad1" spreadMethod="reflect">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color: #ffffff;" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

скрипт

```js
svgPath.setAttribute("stroke", "url(#grad1");`
svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "none");
svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");`
svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-width", "10");
});
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Creating a layer of gradient within an SVG path dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43337435/7394871) от участника  [@Muskan Sethia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7720276/muskan-sethia).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/43337435/7394871

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Решил привести пример анимации появления `polyline`, пришлось заключить `animate` в каждый `polyline`, чтобы получить нужный результат, а далее можно кастомизировать анимацию, как душа пожелает(имею ввиду изменение местоположения(`from="N,N etc."`):

```css
polyline {
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: none;
  animation: opac 3s 1;
}

@keyframes opac {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#4E4E4E" stroke-width="30">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="28">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#6E6E6E" stroke-width="24">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="22">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline> 
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#828282" stroke-width="20">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#8D8D8D" stroke-width="18">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#9F9F9F" stroke-width="16">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#ADADAD" stroke-width="14">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-width="8">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="6">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="4">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
  <polyline points="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25" stroke="#D6D6D6" stroke-width="2">
    <animate attributeName="points" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" from="0,125 150,125 0,125 0,125" to="0,125 150,125 150,25 300,25"/>
  </polyline>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Bharata, всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 9):

Вы не можете сделать градиент  вдоль всего пути, поворачивая его по углам, так как вы хотите.

Если вместо этого вы просто хотите сделать так, чтобы градиент был ориентирован вертикально, то вам нужно использовать атрибуты `x1`, `y1`, `x2` и `y2` для установки строки, вдоль которой выполняется градиент.

Если вы не укажете эти атрибуты, градиент ориентирован горизонтально в соответствии с вашим вторым изображением.

```
<linearGradient id = "grad1" spreadMethod="reflect" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
    <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color: #ffffff;" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
</linearGradient>
```

Если вы хотите иметь эффект «трубы», похожий на градиент, то самым простым способом является многоуровневый путь с разной шириной строк.

```css
svg {
stroke-linejoin:round;
fill:none;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#4E4E4E" stroke-width="30" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="28" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#6E6E6E" stroke-width="24" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="22" /> 
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#828282" stroke-width="20" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#8D8D8D" stroke-width="18" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#9F9F9F" stroke-width="16" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#ADADAD" stroke-width="14" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-width="8" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="6" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="4" />
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#D6D6D6" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

*Прим. переводчика*

Я выбрал этот относительно простой топик для перевода, так как здесь использована оригинальная техника имитации градиента вдоль сложного пути, которая может быть использована на практике и для реализации эффекта анимации постепенного заполнения труб и других емкостей.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Creating a layer of gradient within an SVG path dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346702/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

### Вариант анимации polyline

```css
svg {
stroke-linejoin:round;
fill:none;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#4E4E4E" stroke-width="30" >
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
  </polyline> 
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="28" >
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
  </polyline> 
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#6E6E6E" stroke-width="24" >
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
  </polyline> 
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="22" >
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
  </polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#828282" stroke-width="20" > 
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
 </polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#8D8D8D" stroke-width="18" > 
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
  </polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#9F9F9F" stroke-width="16" > 
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
</polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#ADADAD" stroke-width="14" > 
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />  
 </polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-width="8" >  
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 
</polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="6" >  
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />  
</polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="4" >   
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />  
</polyline>   
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#D6D6D6" stroke-width="2" >  
     <animate attributeName="points" values="0,125;0,125, 150,125;0,125, 150,125 150,25;0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />  
</polyline>   
</svg>
```

### Вариант анимации path

- Переводим координаты `polyline` в координаты `path`
- Всем патчам, которые отвечают за оттенки псевдоградиента присваиваем
  одинаковый класс `class-"poly"`
- анимируем все патчи одновременно, используя атрибуты
  `stroke-dasharray`, `stroke-dashoffset`

```css
svg {
stroke-linejoin:round;
fill:none;
}
.poly {
stroke-dasharray: 850 850;
  stroke-dashoffset: 850;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
} 

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 850;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400"> 
   <path             d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="30" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#4E4E4E" stroke-width="30" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="28" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#6E6E6E" stroke-width="24" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="22" /> 
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#828282" stroke-width="20" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#8D8D8D" stroke-width="18" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#9F9F9F" stroke-width="16" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#ADADAD" stroke-width="14" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-width="8" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="6" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="4" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#D6D6D6" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```